# How do I remove items from the Site Actions menu in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

How can I customise the Site Actions menu to remove or rename 'standard' menu items? Where are the site actions menu items defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site actions menu is defined in the Siteaction.xml in Template\layouts\editingMenu under the 12 hive.  The following link shows how to manually remove items.

[Customize Site Actions Menu](http://blog.avanadeadvisor.com/blogs/marcorizzi/archive/2008/07/23/11483.aspx)

I have added options to the menu using features, but have never tried to hide OTB option in code.  I would be interested in your results.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to hide the menu item I wanted to hide by using `ConfigMenu="Delete"` in the relevant XML node of SiteActions.xml. e.g.

```
 <ConsoleNode ConfigMenu="Delete" ChangedNodeID="wsaCreateSite" />
```

The valid values for ConfigMenu are documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.configmenuoptions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have used a control that runs javascript to hide the entire site actions menu for users of a certain privelege level.

That approach may be an option if you need to remove items for particular users.

It is not the worlds classiest approach however.